# Convert String[] to integer[]

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show images from folder in SD card inside a listview with the names of image files. I tried many adapters
This adapter uses 
    String builder for the name of images
and
    Integer for the images
I get the images from folder as String builder using this code
    File file = new File("sdcard/images");

```
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] listFile = file.listFiles();
       mFileStrings = new String[listFile.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {
            mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
}
```

I want to convert String of this images to integer so that i can use it in adapter.
Because i am getting the following error

```
 Listadapter(String[], integer[]) can not applied to
(String[], String[])
```

How to get the images from folder as Integer?
Or can i edit my listadapter to apply String?

This is my listadapter

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Activity Context;
private final String[] ListItemsName;
private final Integer[] ImageName;

public ListAdapter(Activity context, String[] content,
                   Integer[] ImageName) {

    super(context, R.layout.list_items, content);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.Context = context;
    this.ListItemsName = content;
    this.ImageName = ImageName;
}
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = Context.getLayoutInflater();
    View ListViewSingle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, true);

    TextView ListViewItems = (TextView) ListViewSingle.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView ListViewImage = (ImageView) ListViewSingle.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ListViewItems.setText(ListItemsName[position]);
    ListViewImage.setImageResource(ImageName[position]);
    return ListViewSingle;

};
```

This is my MainActivity

```
File dir = new File("sdcard/images");
        File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
        theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < theNamesOfFiles.length; ii++) {
            theNamesOfFiles[ii] = filelist[ii].getName();
        }
    File file = new File("sdcard/images");
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] listFile = file.listFiles();
       mFileStrings = new String[listFile.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {
            mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
     result = Integer.parseInt(mFileStrings[i]);        
        }
    }
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);   
    ListAdapter la= new ListAdapter(this,theNamesOfFiles,result);
list.setAdapter(la);
    }}
```

Comment: Show the code where you get that error.

Comment: `This one is use String builder for the names of images` ??? I dont see you using a StringBuilder.

Comment: `And integer for the images` Unclear why a number would represent an image.

Comment: which JDK you are using?

Comment: What is `Listadapter`? Doesn't look like an official class, because that would have an uppercase A.

Comment: I update my question and add my adapter code

Comment: And i add my MainActivity

Comment: Then there is currently no answer to your question. You method wants an int array for some reason and we don't know what kind of information it expects. Also, you're reading files and we don't know how these file would look like. What should for example happen when the program reads the file "holiday.png"?

Comment: My error in this line ListAdapter la= new ListAdapter(this,theNamesOfFiles,result);

Comment: `private final Integer[] ImageName;` . No that cannot be an imagename. You are confused. Look at `ListViewImage.setImageResource(ImageName[position]);`. You took some code where images which you at designtime put in for instance the drawable folder would like to display. These images are reachable using an integer like R.drawable.flower (a resource identifier). Instead you should not load from resource but just load from file.

Comment: ListAdapter la= new ListAdapter(this,theNamesOfFiles,mFileStrings);

Comment: How to get images from sdcard folder as integer[]?

Comment: This will solve my problem

Comment: NOOOOOO. NOOOO Not as integer. It cannot solve your problem. You should load the images from file in the ImageView.

Comment: Please give me an example

Comment: There are hundreds of examples to be found on the internet. Already years and years. Many tutorials start with showing images from sdcard in a list view as they name it.

Comment: There is no one form load images from sdcard folder to listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you seriously misunderstand how `ImageView.setImageResource` works. You don't get an image resource integer by passing a file name to `Integer.parseInt`.

```
mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
result = Integer.parseInt(mFileStrings[i]);
```

I'm really not sure why you thought that was going to work. Image resource integers only exist for resources in your app. For images in the filesystem, you could use `BitmapFactory`, but I really recommend just using Glide to make it easier.

Add the following to `app/build.gradle` dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Sync your project, then change your `Listadapter` to this

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<File> imageFiles;

    public ImagesAdapter(List<File> imageFiles) {
        // making a defensive copy of the list
        this.imageFiles = new ArrayList<>(imageFiles);
    }

    public ImagesAdapter(File[] imageFiles) {
        this(Arrays.asList(imageFiles));
    }

    @Override public File getItem(int i) { return imageFiles.get(i); }
    @Override public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
    @Override public int getCount() { return imageFiles.size(); }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View oldView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (oldView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = oldView;
        }

        TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        File file = imageFiles.get(position);
        nameView.setText(file.getName());

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Glide.with(view).load(uri).into(imageView);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Then change your `MainActivity` code to

```
File imagesDir = new File("sdcard/images");
File[] files = imagesDir.listFiles();

list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
list.setAdapter(new ImagesAdapter(files));
```